# creating a new object of Java class returns a null object

Tags: java, class

I have created a new class 'ServiceRequest' like below. I have not added getters and setters here to save space.

```
package testListenerPackage;

import java.util.Date;

public class ServiceRequest {

public static final ServiceRequest REQUEST_ARRIVAL   = new ServiceRequest( "Request_Arrival" );
public static final ServiceRequest REQUEST_COMPLETION   = new ServiceRequest( "Request_Completion" );
public static final ServiceRequest REQUEST_UNDER_PROCESS = new ServiceRequest( "Request_Under_Process" );


private String serviceRequest;
private String requestName;
private int requestID;
private long arrivalTime;
private long startServiceTime;
private long endServiceTime;
private long totalServiceTime;

private String requestStatus;

public enum RequestStatus{
    NEW, COMPLETED
}



public ServiceRequest()
{

}
public ServiceRequest( String serviceRequest ) {
    serviceRequest = serviceRequest;
 }
}
```

When I try to create an instance of this object in other class like this, it returns a null object.

```
  public ServiceRequest generateServiceRequest()
{
    ServiceRequest serviceRequest = new ServiceRequest("Ali baba");
    serviceRequest.setRequestID(1);
    serviceRequest.setRequestName("Read");
    serviceRequest.setRequestStatus(ServiceRequest.REQUEST_ARRIVAL.toString());
    serviceRequest.setArrivalTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return serviceRequest;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "returns a null object"? Are you getting a NullPointerException? Which line?

Comment: Also the line `serviceRequest = serviceRequest;` in your constructor is not accomplishing anything. You need to change it to `this.serviceRequest = serviceRequest;`

Comment: Looks like it should work. Is there _any_ other code that could be causing trouble? Have you stripped it down to _just_ the posted code?

Comment: Likely what's going wrong is this with this expression: `ServiceRequest.REQUEST_ARRIVAL.toString()`. Combined with the fact that `requestStatus` is not properly set, _if_ `toString()` simply delegates to `requestStatus`, that would result in an NPE.  But it's all speculation as the complete code for the class hasn't been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like this code:

```
public ServiceRequest()
{
    // all those references are null - crazy
}
public ServiceRequest(String serviceRequest ) {
    // use "this" to clarify what's initialized
    this.serviceRequest = serviceRequest;
}
```

Comment: this.serviceRequest worked and it does not return null object now. Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

when he meant "null object", he meant that object has nothing in it (his serviceRequest string). As Beau Grantham said "this" will get job done